# How to get the exact block number in Hardhat deploy script?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, blocks, hardhat-deploy

I have written a code in hardhat deploy script to fetch the exact block number at which the contract has been executed, but it usually returns the block next to the original. Any idea how to get the exact block?

My Code:

```
  token = await new DevToken__factory(owner).deploy(1000);
  let contract = await token.deployed();
  let block = await contract.provider?.getBlockNumber();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the TransactionReceipt using its hash and inside it, you can see the block at which the contract is deployed

```
  token = await new DevToken__factory(owner).deploy(1000);
  const hashOfTx = token.deployTransaction.hash
  let contract = await token.deployed();
  
  let txReceipt = await contract.provider.getTransactionReceipt(hashOfTx);
  console.log(txReceipt.blockNumber)
```

Comment: I think it worked. The block number returned is exactly the one expected. Thanks. :)